Vue.js image error : Cannot find module, check if image exists
I am using Vue 3, trying to display an image.
<img :src="require(`../../assets/icons/` + element.icon)"
@error="imageUrlAlt"
class="avatar sm rounded-pill flex-shrink-0"
alt="wrong image">

It works find when image exists, but the image name is provided by back-end and sometimes can be wrong (null or not existing image).
This leads to the error : Cannot find module './wrong-name.jpg'
I found some error check using @error, this is the method :
  methods: {
    imageUrlAlt(event) {
            event.target.src = "default.png"
        }
    }

But it doesn't seem to trigger, I guess due to the "require" in image src.
Is there a way to test if image exists or test (try catch) the require result ?
Edit : Updated the example to make it clearer.
The image name can be null OR with a wrong name (since multi fronts can edit database).
I tried the different answers but I still get the error raised when the image name is wrong.
More info : I added a log into the imageUrlAlt method and it seems that the @error doesn't trigger well when the require is having an error.

like this
<img :src="imageUrlAlt(element.icon)">

methods: {
    imageUrlAlt(icon) {
          return require(icon ? `../../assets/icons/${icon}` : 'default.png')
    }
}


Update your error handler to:
imageUrlAlt(event) {
    event.target.src = require('@/assets/images/default-image.jpg')  // Path to your default local image
}


You should not get too comfortable using js inside the  section in directives or within the double curly brackets.
Better use helper functions and directives like computed() and expose data like that from the  section, as shown by xianrong lei.
I think this is a good use case for computed
 import { computed } from 'vue';

 const imageUrl = computed(() => {
   if (...) {
     return ...
   }

   return placeholder;
 });



Consider using v-once on images
Use the alt attribute on images
Use a computed const with an string being:

// template
<img v-if="!!imgSrc" v-once :src="imgSrc" alt="image" />

// script
const imgSrc = computed<string>(() => !!element?.icon ? `../../assets/icons/${element?.icon}` : '');

and display the img only when element?.icon is truthy
